# problems mounting an external IDE drive via USB in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, pata

I am having a problem connecting a specific IDE drive to my linux box.  It's an old drive which I just want to get about 3 GB of files off of.

### INFO

- I am trying to connect a 200GB IDE Maxtor Drive, internally and externally...
- externally:

  - I am using an self powered USB IDE external drive enclosure which I have used to connect various drives, under ubuntu and windows, in the past.  The other posts stated it coudl be a problem
  - I think i may have formatted the /dev/sdc partition instead of /dev/sdc1 partition when i originally formatted the drive.
- internally:

  - I only have one machine left that has an internal IDE interface, and it's got XP on it.
  - I plugged this drive internally into this machine with windows XP and used the ext2/ext3 drivers to mount this drive, but some files have question marks (?) in the file names which is messing up my copy process in windows.  I can't delete the files under windows.
  - Ubuntu Linux will not install on my only remaining machine that has IDE controller.

I have tried the suggestions in the questions below

[mount an external drive in Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/88182/mount-an-external-drive-in-ubuntu)

[Ubuntu fails to mount USB drive](https://superuser.com/questions/23210/ubuntu-fails-to-mount-usb-drive)

it looks like i can see the drive in /proc/partitions

```
$ cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

   8        0   78125000 sda
   8        1   74894998 sda1
   8        2          1 sda2
   8        5    3229033 sda5
   8       16  199148544 sdb <-- could be my drive?
```

but it's not listed under fdisk -l

```
$ fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 80.0 GB, 80000000000 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 9726 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xd0f4738c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1        9324    74894998+  83  Linux
/dev/sda2            9325        9726     3229065    5  Extended
/dev/sda5            9325        9726     3229033+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

and here is my log of /var/log/messages.   with a bunch of weird output, can someone let me know what that weird output is?

```
Mar  3 19:49:40 mala kernel: [687455.112029] usb 1-7: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 3
Mar  3 19:49:41 mala kernel: [687455.248576] usb 1-7: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Mar  3 19:49:41 mala kernel: [687455.267450] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
Mar  3 19:49:41 mala kernel: [687455.269180] scsi4 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
Mar  3 19:49:41 mala kernel: [687455.269410] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
Mar  3 19:49:41 mala kernel: [687455.269416] USB Mass Storage support registered.
Mar  3 19:49:46 mala kernel: [687460.270917] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Maxtor 6 Y200P0           YAR4 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Mar  3 19:49:46 mala kernel: [687460.271485] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Mar  3 19:49:46 mala kernel: [687460.278858] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 398297088 512-byte logical blocks: (203 GB/189 GiB)
Mar  3 19:49:46 mala kernel: [687460.280866] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
Mar  3 19:50:16 mala kernel: [687460.283784]  sdb:
Mar  3 19:50:16 mala kernel: [687491.112020] usb 1-7: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 3
Mar  3 19:50:47 mala kernel: [687522.120030] usb 1-7: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 3
Mar  3 19:51:18 mala kernel: [687553.112034] usb 1-7: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 3
Mar  3 19:51:49 mala kernel: [687584.116025] usb 1-7: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 3
Mar  3 19:52:02 mala kernel: [687596.170632] type=1505 audit(1267671122.035:31): operation="profile_replace" pid=8426 name=/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf
Mar  3 19:52:02 mala kernel: [687596.171551] type=1505 audit(1267671122.035:32): operation="profile_replace" pid=8426 name=/usr/sbin/cupsd
Mar  3 19:52:06 mala kernel: [687600.908056] async/0       D c08145c0     0  7655      2 0x00000000
Mar  3 19:52:06 mala kernel: [687600.908062]  e5601d38 00000046 e5774000 c08145c0 e4c2a848 c08145c0 d203973a 0002713d
Mar  3 19:52:06 mala kernel: [687600.908072]  c08145c0 c08145c0 e4c2a848 c08145c0 00000000 0002713d c08145c0 f0a98c00
Mar  3 19:52:06 mala kernel: [687600.908079]  e4c2a5b0 c20125c0 00000002 e5601d80 e5601d44 c056f3be e5601d78 e5601d4c
Mar  3 19:52:06 mala kernel: [687600.908087] Call Trace:
Mar  3 19:52:06 mala kernel: [687600.908099]  [<c056f3be>] io_schedule+0x1e/0x30
Mar  3 19:52:06 mala kernel: [687600.908107]  [<c01b2cf5>] sync_page+0x35/0x40
Mar  3 19:52:06 mala kernel: [687600.908111]  [<c056f8f7>] __wait_on_bit_lock+0x47/0x90
Mar  3 19:52:06 mala kernel: [687600.908115]  [<c01b2cc0>] ? sync_page+0x0/0x40
Mar  3 19:52:06 mala kernel: [687600.908121]  [<c020f390>] ? blkdev_readpage+0x0/0x20
Mar  3 19:52:06 mala kernel: [687600.908125]  [<c01b2ca9>] __lock_page+0x79/0x80
Mar  3 19:52:06 mala kernel: [687600.908130]  [<c015c130>] ? wake_bit_function+0x0/0x50
Mar  3 19:52:06 mala kernel: [687600.908135]  [<c01b459f>] read_cache_page_async+0xbf/0xd0
Mar  3 19:52:06 mala kernel: [687600.908139]  [<c01b45c2>] read_cache_page+0x12/0x60
Mar  3 19:52:06 mala kernel: [687600.908144]  [<c0232dca>] read_dev_sector+0x3a/0x80
Mar  3 19:52:06 mala kernel: [687600.908148]  [<c0233d3e>] adfspart_check_ICS+0x1e/0x160
Mar  3 19:52:06 mala kernel: [687600.908152]  [<c023339f>] ? disk_name+0xaf/0xc0
Mar  3 19:52:06 mala kernel: [687600.908157]  [<c0233d20>] ? adfspart_check_ICS+0x0/0x160
Mar  3 19:52:06 mala kernel: [687600.908161]  [<c02334de>] check_partition+0x10e/0x180
Mar  3 19:52:06 mala kernel: [687600.908165]  [<c02335f6>] rescan_partitions+0xa6/0x330
Mar  3 19:52:06 mala kernel: [687600.908171]  [<c0312472>] ? kobject_get+0x12/0x20
Mar  3 19:52:06 mala kernel: [687600.908175]  [<c0312472>] ? kobject_get+0x12/0x20
Mar  3 19:52:06 mala kernel: [687600.908180]  [<c039fc43>] ? get_device+0x13/0x20
Mar  3 19:52:06 mala kernel: [687600.908185]  [<c03c263f>] ? sd_open+0x5f/0x1b0
Mar  3 19:52:06 mala kernel: [687600.908189]  [<c020fda0>] __blkdev_get+0x140/0x310
Mar  3 19:52:06 mala kernel: [687600.908194]  [<c020f0ac>] ? bdget+0xec/0x100
Mar  3 19:52:06 mala kernel: [687600.908198]  [<c020ff7a>] blkdev_get+0xa/0x10
Mar  3 19:52:06 mala kernel: [687600.908202]  [<c0232f30>] register_disk+0x120/0x140
Mar  3 19:52:06 mala kernel: [687600.908207]  [<c0308b4d>] ? blk_register_region+0x2d/0x40
Mar  3 19:52:06 mala kernel: [687600.908211]  [<c03084f0>] ? exact_match+0x0/0x10
Mar  3 19:52:06 mala kernel: [687600.908216]  [<c0308cf0>] add_disk+0x80/0x140
Mar  3 19:52:06 mala kernel: [687600.908221]  [<c03084f0>] ? exact_match+0x0/0x10
Mar  3 19:52:06 mala kernel: [687600.908225]  [<c0308860>] ? exact_lock+0x0/0x20
Mar  3 19:52:06 mala kernel: [687600.908230]  [<c03c53df>] sd_probe_async+0xff/0x1c0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be going down the data recovery route with some tools instead of just mounting the drive.  It sounds like you blew away the partition table.  Something I found that may help: [TestDisk, Data Recovery TestDisk, Data Recovery](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)